# Azure DevOps Build - publish doesn't create .compiled files in bin folder on publish

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-devops, web-deployment, precompile, pre-compilation

I have a web project I am building and creating a published package from Azure-DevOps Build pipeline.

I am running with the issue that not getting .compile files in bin folder while publishing. when I am publishing from the direct build machine's VS 2015(**on which azure-DevOps builds are also running**) I am getting all .compile files.

**My .pubxml file**

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <PrecompileBeforePublish>True</PrecompileBeforePublish>
    <EnableUpdateable>False</EnableUpdateable>
    <DebugSymbols>True</DebugSymbols>
    <WDPMergeOption>CreateSeparateAssembly</WDPMergeOption>
    <UseFixedNames>True</UseFixedNames>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <publishUrl>E:\DevOps\agent\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.136.1\QAWeb_Artifacts</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

**Task configuration in Azure-DevOps pipeline**

[image]

I found the same issue here - https://forums.asp.net/t/1984856.aspx but not answered.

Please Suggest what I am missing when I build and publish my website from azure-DevOps.

Comment: First off, **do not hard-code agent paths**. Use variables such as `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`. Hard-coded paths will fail when run on other agents or if you clone the build definition.

Comment: @DanielMann Yes, I get it.But my problem is still there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Manager found an answer !!

**Solution -** 
Whenever we choose task 'Visual Studio Build' it is not different from 'MSBuild build' task except MSBuild version which we want to run. So if I give `/p:PublishProfile=/my/publishProfile/PUBXML` as an argument it won't work. Rather than all parameter should be in 'MSbuild arguments' Section directly of build task.

**Now My Visual Studio task configuration look like**,
[image]

This works great!