# How to use publish profile options from Visual Studio in azure pipelines?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, azure-devops, msbuild, azure-pipelines

I have an ASP.NET project and I want to implement CI-CD using Azure pipelines, to deploy to custom server (IIS). 
Currently, when using Visual Studio(2019) to publish web application manually, I am using these options for publish profile:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <PublishProvider>FileSystem</PublishProvider>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>True</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <publishUrl>C:\Test</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
    <PrecompileBeforePublish>True</PrecompileBeforePublish>
    <EnableUpdateable>False</EnableUpdateable>
    <DebugSymbols>False</DebugSymbols>
    <WDPMergeOption>MergeEachIndividualFolder</WDPMergeOption>
    <UseMerge>True</UseMerge>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

The main thing that I want to achieve, is implementing `<WDPMergeOption>MergeEachIndividualFolder</WDPMergeOption>` when deploying using build and release pipeline.

- For release pipeline, I am using IIS Web Deployment.
- For build pipeline agent sepcification, I am using vs2017-win2016
- For build solution task, I am using latest version of visual stidio

Things I've tried:

**1. Passing configuration arguments to msbuild, for Build Solution task in azure build pipeline:**

```
/p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory) /p:OutputPath=bin 

/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem  /p:PrecompileBeforePublish=true 

/p:EnableUpdateable=false /p:DebugSymbols=true  /p:UseMerge=true /p:DeleteAppCodeCompiledFiles=True 

/p:DeleteExistingFiles=True  /p:WDPMergeOption=MergeEachIndividualFolder /p:UseFixedNames=true\\"
```

**2. Uploading FolderProfile.pubxml , and passing arguments to msbuild to read from that file**

It all builds and releases fine, but doesn't merge assemblies in release, as configured with merge options, it seems like `msbuild` ignores these additional merge arguments.

How can this be done, the main question is how can I use `MergeEachIndividualFolder` option when deploying with azure pipeline?

I've also searched a lot, but non of the questions seems to cover the solution.

[Azure DevOps Build - publish doesn't create .compiled files in bin folder on publish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53931787/azure-devops-build-publish-doesnt-create-compiled-files-in-bin-folder-on-pub)

[MSBuild commandline seems to ignore publish properties](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/1901)

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT If by `xxx` you mean path to `FolderProfile.pubxml`, yes I've tried that

Comment: `xxxx` means the profile name: `/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile`

Comment: How's your issue going? Is the argument working?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure DevOps Build - publish doesn't create .compiled files in bin folder on publish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53931787/azure-devops-build-publish-doesnt-create-compiled-files-in-bin-folder-on-pub)

Answer (score 2):

The recommendation from Cece Dong - MSFT worked in my instance of using a publish profile.

Snippet below YML

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: 'Path\MySolution.sln'
    vsVersion: '16.0'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=myProfile.pubxml'
    configuration: 'Release'
```

Then in the output the build you can see it having the desired effect:

*WebFileSystemPublish:
Creating directory "C:\MyPublishPath".
Copying obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\File1.ext to C:\MyPublishPath\File1.ext.
Copying obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\File2.ext to C:\MyPublishPath\File2.ext.
Copying obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\File3.ext to C:\MyPublishPath\bin\File3.ext.
Copying obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\File4.ext to C:\MyPublishPath\bin\File4.ext.
... all other files included in the publish*